# Конвертировать object php в object JSON или в object c#

Tags: php, c#, mysql, json

В базе данных MYSQL хранятся данные в формате object php например так

```
a:3:{s:8:"Цвет";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"*";}s:24:"Шарнир";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"*";}s:14:"Уголок";a:1:{i:0;s:49:"Левый";}}
```

Используется dotnet core 2.1.4. 
Чем можно десерилизовать эти данные например в JSON или object c#?

Comment: А можно где то почитать про этот чудо формат `object php`?  Первый раз о нем слышу, а гугл молчит... Ну или хотя бы метод, который в PHP сгенерирует подобное. Тогда бы я поигрался и может что нашли вместе!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `serialize($obj)`

Comment: Можно попробовать сторонней библиотекой, например как говорят [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923626/6808809). Но я бы советовал вам перевести все это в один из распространенных форматов (json/xml) на php.

Comment: Вот как раз и хотел перевести во что то приличное

Comment: Вы можете сколь угодно долго ждать решения с использованием c#, либо решить эту одноразовую (?) задачу штатными средствами пхп. Запустили один раз конвертацию, пересохранили в json и все. Зачем вам тут решение на c# не ясно.

Comment: в БД более 10млн записей и постоянно пополняются таками объектами переконвертировать не получится

Comment: дак и перестаньте пополнять такими объектами. новые пополняйте уже закодированными в json  а не сериализованными в php. А существующие не важно каким образом перекодить, на пхп или шарпе, все равно сделать это придется на клиенте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал метод десирилизации объекта php в объект с#. Может кому пригодится:

```
 /// <summary>
    ////Парсер для объекта PHP
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="phpObject">Строка для разбора</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Tuple<string, List<string>>> ParserPHPObject(string phpObject)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new List<Tuple<string, List<string>>>();

            foreach (var item in phpObject.Split(new string[] { "{s" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
            {
                foreach (var itemf in item.Split(new string[] { "}s" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                {
                    if (itemf.Length > 4)
                    {
                        List<string> attr = new List<string>();
                        string par = itemf.Split(';')[0].Split(':').LastOrDefault();
                        var var1 = itemf.Split(new string[] { ";a" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(';');

                        foreach (var bb in var1)
                        {
                            if (!bb.Contains("i:") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bb))
                            {
                                if (bb.Contains("s:49"))
                                {
                                    attr.Add("http:" + bb.Split(':').LastOrDefault());
                                }
                                else if (bb.Contains("s:"))
                                {
                                    attr.Add(bb.Split(':').LastOrDefault());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        var tp = Tuple.Create(par, attr);
                        result.Add(tp);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```